# Forecasting, (finding the right model)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, forecasting

Using Python, I am trying to predict the future sales count of a product, using historical sales data. I am also trying to predict these counts for various groups of products.

For example, my columns looks like this:

```
Date Sales_count Department Item Color

8/1/2018, 50, Homegoods, Hats, Red_hat
```

If I want to build a model that predicts the sales_count for each Department/Item/Color combo using historical data (time), what is the best model to use?

If I do Linear regression on time against sales, how do I account for various categories? Can I group them?

Would I instead use multilinear regression, treating the various categories as independent variables?

Comment: One of the most common model for timeseries forecasting is ARIMA (Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average). This is a good tutorial on how to do analysis & forecast timeseries data with ARIMA https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecast-study-python-monthly-sales-french-champagne/

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have come across in forecasting in python is using SARIMAX( Seasonal Auto Regressive Integrated Moving Average with Exogenous Variables) model in statsmodel Library. Here is the link for a very good tutorial in [SARIMAX using python](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3)
Also, If you are able to group the data frame according to your Department/Item?color combo, you can put them in a loop and apply the same model.
May be you can create a key for each unique combination and for each key condition you can forecast the sales.
For example,

```
df=pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
df['key']=df['Department']+'_'+df['Item']+'_'+df['Color']
for key in df['key'].unique():
    temp=df.loc[df['key']==key]#filtering only the specific group
    temp=temp.groupby('Date')['Sales_count'].sum().reset_index()
    #aggregating the sum of sales in that date. Ignore if not required. 
    #write the forecasting code here from the tutorial
```